# I need to auto_increment a field in MySQL that is not primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

Right now, I have a table whose primary key is an `auto_increment` field. However, I need to set the primary key as `username`, `date` (to ensure that there cannot be a duplicate username with a date).

I need the `auto_increment` field, however, in order to make changes to row information (adding and deleting).

What is normally done with this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just set a unique index on composite of (username, date).

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`username`, `date`);
```

Alternatively, you can try to

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(`username`,`date`);
```

and I think in the latter case you need those columns to be declared NOT NULL.

Comment: @littleK i have two field i want to set one as primary key and another as a auto increment is it possible?

Comment: You cannot drop the first primary key if it's auto-increment. The second solution you provided won't work.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old question, here is how i solved the problem -

```
ALTER TABLE `student_info` ADD `sn` INT(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

Answer (score 4):

Use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  thedate DATE NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(user,thedate)
);
```

If you already have the table, and just want to add a unique constraint on
user+thedate, run

```
ALTER TABLE users  ADD UNIQUE KEY user_date_idx (user,  thedate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your current primary key to be a unique key instead:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD UNIQUE KEY(username,date);
```

The auto_increment will function normally after that without any problems.  You should also place a unique key on the auto_increment field as well, to use for your row handling:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY(id);
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way, however was still getting the error:

#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key