# Set AUTO_INCREMENT using SqlAlchemy with MySQL on Columns with non-primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, auto-increment

I can't figure out how to set AUTO_INCREMENT on a UNIQUE column using SqlAlchemy 0.6.0 with MySQL 5.

I know this can be done in MySQL, but I don't want to have to distribute extra .sql scripts in order to set up the databases for my application. I want SqlAlchemy to build the schema from within Python.

As far as I have found so far, there are two ways that a column can become an auto-incrementing type column in SqlAlchemy:

1. It is the first `sqlalchemy.types.Integer` column in the table that has `primary_key=True` and does not have `autoincrement=False` set in its definition.

   - With MSSQL this adds an `INDEX(m,n)` property to the column.
   - With Postgres this causes the `SERIAL` column type to be used.
   - With MySQL adds the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property to the column.
2. It is an `sqlalchemy.types.Integer` column, and is instantiated with an `sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence` object as an argument.

   - With MSSQL this adds an `INDEX(m,n)` property to the column.
   - With Postgres this causes the `SERIAL` column type to be used.
   - With MySQL this seems to get ignored.

So I can't use #1 because the column I want to auto_increment isn't in the primary key (nor should it be). And I can't use #2 because It doesn't work with MySQL.

Basically, my code to define the table looks like the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Unicode
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    first_name = Column(Unicode(100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(Unicode(100), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

And produces this SQL to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (first_name, last_name), 
    UNIQUE (id)
)
```

What can I do to get it to produce the following SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (first_name, last_name), 
    UNIQUE (id)
)
```

Comment: Until now I have never managed to do this even directly in MySQL, because I never tried to explicitly mark the non-primary key auto-incremented field as UNIQUE. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 6):

Excerpt from http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg19744.html

> Your best bet for now is to issue an `ALTER TABLE` that applies the 
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT`, if MySQL supports that.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDL
DDL("ALTER TABLE person ...", on='mysql').execute_at('after-create', 
    person_table)[..]
```

Comment: You might want to hook that statement into the table creation machienry so that it's executed at the right time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039046/in-sqlalchemy-how-do-i-define-an-event-to-fire-ddl-using-declarative-syntax for an example.

Comment: `execute_at` is deprecated since v0.7. see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DDLElement.execute_at

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [I need to auto_increment a field in MySQL that is not primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151314/i-need-to-auto-increment-a-field-in-mysql-that-is-not-primary-key)

I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy, but I do know this can be accomplished in MySQL. You must first define the `id` column as the `PRIMARY KEY` and set it `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Then you can `ALTER TABLE` and `DROP PRIMARY KEY`, replacing it with an `ADD UNIQUE KEY`. This will preserve the `AUTO_INCREMENT` functionality on that column. You can then create the `PRIMARY KEY` on the other columns.

To break it down, your first step is to create the table thusly:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Next modify the `id` key:

```
ALTER TABLE person DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD UNIQUE KEY(id);
```

Finally, add your `PRIMARY KEY` on the other columns:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD PRIMARY KEY(first_name, last_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Dustin.

It looks like if I'm going to do it by executing an ALTER TABLE, I should be able to do it by keeping everything as-is and executing a single "ALTER TABLE person CHANGE id id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;". I'll post back when I figure out how to do this in Python.

Comment: Great, I would love to hear your feedback on whether this approach works for you with sqlalchemy.